# ldapmodify script

Tags: linux, scripting, ldap

I'm trying to modify a lot of users logins without a certain pattern in LDAP from a text file but I'm getting errors:

This is my try:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat users.txt`; do ldapmodify -h 10.X.X.X -p 389 -x -D "cn=admin" -w password; done << EOF
dn: cn=$i,ou=Userstomodify,o=wkd
changetype:modify
replace:telexnumber
telexnumber:19900101
EOF
```

`ldapmodify` is working OK in a terminal manually but not in this script.

Comment: What error are you getting ? Have you tried `set -x` after the shebang (#!/bin/bash) before the for loop ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273665/what-does-set-x-do for info

Answer (score 2):

Your code is broken!

You want to modify the LDAP entries for every user in users.txt, not just the first, right ?

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n Password: 
read -s password

for i in `cat users.txt`; do ldapmodify -h 10.X.X.X -p 389 -x -D "cn=admin" -w $password << EOF
dn: cn=$i,ou=Userstomodify,o=wkd
changetype:modify
replace:telexnumber
telexnumber:19900101
EOF
done
```

Comment: That's not working. I'm getting error in line 12

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I had not tested my latest change ... was attempting to hide the password ... thanks for letting me know and, next time, I will test every change I make to code!